# Swap function for gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclicklistener

I have a gridview with images, and want to allow swapping when clicking an image.

This is in the onClickListener:

```
            int blank = 0;
            int click = position;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if ((Integer)gridView.getChildAt(i).getTag() == size - 1) {
                    blank = i;
                }
            swap();
            gridView.invalidateViews();
```

and this is the swap function

```
    private void swap() {
        Bitmap temp = bmparray[click];
        bmparray[click] = bmparray[blank];
        bmparray[blank] = temp;
    }
```

When I run this is what the logcat gives me:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException

This is at the first line of the swap function. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @ChrisSprague http://pastebin.com/yN8nLTRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code from the swap function to the place where the swap function is called fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure bmparray[click] doesn't overextend the array size?

also "click" and "blank" variables are declared inside OnClickListener. Looks like you should pass those as arguments to swap function. Normally you should get a compiler error. I'm guessing there are also global variables named click and blank.